# FreeRTOS xQueueSelectFromSet stuck on full queue

Tags: freertos

my queue set seems to be ignoring the full queue.
xQueueSelectFromSet() always times out, but the queue is full and it can be read.
Here is a simplified example of my situation.

Did I misunderstood something and have false expectations, or is such behavior expected?

ISR:

```
if(xQueueIsQueueFullFromISR(queue)){
  xQueueReceiveFromISR(queue, &dummy, &pxHigherPriorityTaskWoken);
}
xQueueSendFromISR(queue, event, &pxHigherPriorityTaskWoken);
```

task2:

```
xQueueSet = xQueueCreateSet(QUEUE_LENGTH + 1);
xQueueAddToSet(queue, xQueueSet);
xQueueAddToSet(semaphore, xQueueSet);
while(true){
  xActivatedMember = xQueueSelectFromSet(xQueueSet, 100);
  if(xActivatedMember == semaphore){
    xSemaphoreTake(semaphore, 0);
    break; // from the infinite loop
  }else if(xActivatedMember == queue){
    // read from queue
  }else if(xActivatedMember == NULL){
    // timed out but queue is full
    uxQueueMessagesWaiting(queue); // returns QUEUE_LENGTH
    xQueueReceive(queue, &event, 0); // reads without problem
  } // xActivatedMember 
} // infinite loop
```

Comment: xQueueIsQueueFullFromISR should exclusively used in ISR code/context, not in tasks (as documented). You add 'queue' to the set but check for '_i2sEventQueue' ? And I don't get the purpose of task1.

Comment: Sorry, it's a mistake. The first task is ISR and it is using the appropriate version of calls. The other one is not ISR.
The second one is also an editing error while simplifying for this post.
The ISR simply handles MCU module and sends events to queue for other tasks only to notify them its job is completed.
I have edited the first task to ISR (in this example).

Comment: Should work (now). However, I still don't get the purpose of the queue full-check/dummy receive in the ISR.

Comment: The ISR is not my code, but I assume it's there simply to not overflow the queue.

Comment: That's done anyway by xQueueSendFromISR. It returns pdTRUE if the data was successfully sent to the queue, otherwise errQUEUE_FULL.